# Database list datatype

Tags: database, database-design

Hey I got the following Problem:

```
Foods (is a Food (egg, milk, etc) OR a Recipe (bread, which is made out of eggs, flour, etc) ).
PK: foodId
FK: recipeId

Recipe (contains 1..many foods) Bread - eggs, flour, etc..
PK: recipeId
String: name
String: cooking
FK: foodId, foodId2, foodId3, ...

Meal (many foods = a meal) bread + marmelade + coffee
PK: mealId
String: name
FK: foodId, foodId2, foodId,3, ...
```

How can I create something like this in a database?

I cant create more than 1 Entry with the same PK.

```
So example:

Recipe:
recipeId: 1
name: bread
cooking: mix all ingredients and then bake.
foodId: 1 (milk)

recipeId: 1
name: bread
cooking: mix all ingredients and then bake.
foodId: 2 (flour)
```

This is not possible due to the duplicate PK in recipeId.

I hope you understand my question and can provide an answer.

Comment: Start with a table of recipes, a table of ingredients, and a table which specifies how much of each ingredient is used in each recipe. In some instances, the same ingredient may be used twice ('dust with caster sugar', 'glaze with butter','egg wash', 'reserve a little olive oil/parsley', etc.), but you can decide whether to relate that to recipes or to recipe steps.

Comment: You don't say what your implementation is going to be.  Are you using a database system (a DBMS)?  Or a language such as Java, coupled with file storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something more like:

```
Recipe
----
RecipeId
Name
PrepTime
CookTime
CuisineType

RecipeSteps
----
StepId
RecipeId
Instructions

RecipeStepIngredients
----
Id
StepId
FoodId
```

Note, this is far from perfect, but could at least get you started.

Basically:

> A meal can have many recipes
>
> A recipe can have many steps
>
> A single step can have many ingredients (be made up of several food items)

Comment: This is kind of meh... It will work I guess, but I have to create meals for breakfest, dinner, lunch, for a whole week for like 100 patients in the database. I can only imagine how complicated linking all of this would be and how long it would take for the program to read all this values from the DB.

Comment: Cuisine type might be a separate table - For instance 'Japanese' and 'Vegetarian' are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Vulkanos You've got that back to front. Relational databases LOVE normalized data. And they chomp through it at a tremendous rate. MySQL wouldn't even break sweat at something so trivial as 2100 rows.

Comment: @Strawberry indeed.  I guess "some" could be exclusive.  "Vegetarian/Steak" :P  But yeah I guess even "Japanese" and "Latin" aren't necessarily exclusive.  I love Japanese Latin fusion!

Comment: @Strawberry oh, okey I didnt knew that. Thank you for that information. I'll consider your answer then.

Comment: Keep in mind once you have a catalog of "recipes" you don't have to keep creating those tedious recipes over and over again.  When planning meals you can in effect just add a number of recipes to a meal.  If you get really detailed, with amounts of ingredient and the like, you could even create things like an inventory management/ordering system based on the meals and quantities you have planned for a given week.